# Creating a socket client in Objective-C - Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, client

I need to basically send some "data" to 98.136.86.109 at port 587. How can I do this in obj-c in my mac app?

Comment: Just a note - it's generally unwise to specify real public IP addresses when asking questions in a public forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yan notes in his answer, you could use the standard BSD-style networking APIs like `socket()`, `connect()`, etc. However, if you want to stay in Objective C and Foundation, then you're looking for `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`, which are the stream classes for Cocoa. You should not, however, look at `NSSocketPort` as that's specifically for use with Distributed Objects.

Apple's "Introduction to Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa" is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html

You should start with that document and then check out the class references which have pointers to sample code projects which use `NSStream` and its subclasses.

Comment: You can, however, use the `-socket` from `NSSocketPort` to obtain a native socket handle - a file descriptor. Thereby, it is usable for non-DO applications to more easily create a socket. Like any wrapper intended to ease use, it does make some nice things like `SO_REUSEADDR` trickier to use.

Comment: Sure, but all the other code in `NSSocketPort` is there specifically to handle DO transport. While you can get a socket from one, it wouldn't be correct to keep that socket and throw away the `NSSocketPort` instance (you don't know what it's going to do with the socket on `dealloc`).

Comment: Agreed, you couldn't throw it away. Still, depending on what one is doing, it can be an easier way to obtain a socket. For example, for education purposes, it could be easier to just show people that `NSSocketPort` can "maintain" a socket than to show them how to properly create BSD sockets.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t mind using third-party code, [AsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is a popular library that wraps `CFSocket` and `CFStream`, providing an Objective-C API for communication via TCP and UDP (AsyncUdpSocket).

Comment: AsyncSocket was very easy to use. Example code provided. Built with ARC. Thank you so much!!!