# How to implement client Socket in objective-c

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, sockets

i need to do the same of this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientSocketExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //
            // Create a connection to the server socket on the server application
            //
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7777);

            //
            // Send a message to the client application
            //
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("Hello There...");

            //
            // Read and display the response message sent by server application
            //
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but in objective-c, i see that there are many classes that uses socket, but i don't know how to use it in an iphone project, can someone help me? thanks!!!

Comment: refer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240696/creating-a-socket-client-in-objective-c-mac-osx

Comment: You can only use ObjectInput/OutputStream with another Java program. I suggest you use a portable format like XML, JSon or another text protocol instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may upload it Asynchronously, record it completely ,then fully upload it after

or just [NSStream](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)  or pure TCP Socket as in unix and i use [cocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
}
```